# Is it possible to extend graphql response other than just data for pagination?

Tags: express, response, graphql

In GraphQL response normally looks like followings.

```
{
  "data": [{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "Jon Snow",
    "email": "crow@northofthew.all",
    "age": 20
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "username": "Tyrion Lannister",
    "email": "drunk@i.mp",
    "age": 34
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "username": "Sansa Stark",
    "email": "redhead@why.me",
    "age": 17
  }]
}
```

Is it possible to add meta data to your response such as pagination like this.

```
{
  "pagination": {
    "total": 14,
    "count": 230,
  },
  "data": [{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "Jon Snow",
    "email": "crow@northofthew.all",
    "age": 20
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "username": "Tyrion Lannister",
    "email": "drunk@i.mp",
    "age": 34
  }]
}
```

I'm using express-graphql and currently put those pagination to custom response header, which is fine but it can be better. Since GraphQL response is already wrapped with "data", it is not very strange to add more "data" to its response.

Comment: Based on the specification, that would not be [a valid GraphQL response](http://facebook.github.io/graphql/#sec-Response-Format) ("To ensure future changes to the protocol do not break existing servers and clients, the top level response map must not contain any entries other than the three described above."). You could package that in an `extensions` key, I guess, or [use other pagination approaches](http://graphql.org/learn/pagination/).

Comment: @CommonsWare You're right. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reenforcing what @CommonsWare already stated, according to the specification that would a be an invalid GraphQL response. Regarding pagination, Relay has its own pagination approach called [connections](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/graphql-connections.html), but indeed, several other approaches are possible and even more suitable in some situtations (connections aren't a silver bullet).

I want to augment what was already said by adding that the hierarchical nature of GraphQL incites related data to be at the same level. An example is worth a thousands words, so here it goes:

```
query Q {
  pagination_info { # what is this info related to? completely unclear
    total
    count
  }
  user {
    friends {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Instead...

```
query Q {
  user {
    friends {
      pagination_info { # fairly obvious that this is related to friends
        total
        count
      }
      friend {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's totally make sense. I got what that means. Thanks.